# Last build number of mercurial in cruise control .net

Tags: mercurial, cruisecontrol.net

We are using cruise control .net with mercurial version control for continuous integration.
I want to get the latest build number in the ccnet dashboard.

While using toroise svn as version control we added **`<labeller type="lastChangeLabeller"/>`** to get the latest build number. So while using mercurial hg, what tag should be added in order to get the latest build number? Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what it looks like in cruise control (people still use cruise control?!), but from mercurial you can use: `hg log -r . --template '{node}-{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance}'` to get the string you want.  You can exec that and get the value either in CC or in your build scripts.

Comment: thanks for your support. We created a bat file and executed from ccnet to get latest tag